# Generate JAR with Hibernate, Spring Boot and JavaFX

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, javafx, jar

I have a problem with creating JAR with application using Spring Boot and Hibernate. 
I were also trying to generate similar JAR from app using only Spring Boot without Hibernate and everything works fine.

It's JavaFX desktop appliaction connected with MySQL database.

EDIT:
I Need to highlight, that everything works fine, when application is starting from IDE (IntelliJ). Problem is only with starting app from generated JAR

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at pl.settlement.SettlementApplication.main(SettlementApplication.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:236)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 53 more
```

pom.xml:

```
<groupId>pl</groupId>
<artifactId>settlement</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>settlement</name>
<description>Settlements</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>pl.settlement.SettlementApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>pl.settlement.SettlementApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/settlement?useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/settlement</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CountryEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CurrencyEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CurrencyRateEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CurrencyTableEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.DailyRateEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.DriverEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.DriverChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.FuellingEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.FuellingImportEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderEventEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderEventTypeEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderIncomeEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderIncomeTypeEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderOutcomeEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderOutcomePaymentMethodEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderOutcomeTypeEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderStatusEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderTollEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.SupplierEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TrailerEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TrailerChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TruckEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TruckChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.UserEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.UserChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.UserPermissionsEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.VatRateEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CompanyFixedCostsEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CompanyFixedCostsChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TourEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TourChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.TourStatusEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.MeasurementEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CountryChangeLogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CustomerEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.CompanyEntity"/>
        <mapping class="pl.settlement.Entities.OrderEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Trying getting rid of your `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` line. Normally spring boot can deduce from the url. Add spaces before and after all `=`. Ensure your db is up and actually running

Comment: All spaces before and after all = didn't make any result. Removing line  spring.datasource.driver-class-name causing another exception

Comment: Sorry, I've messed up in pom.xml. Now, when I've correct pom.xml and application.properties, application is running without line spring.datasource.driver-class-name, but still only from IDE, not from JAR. Please check updated question with correct pom.xml and application.properties files

Comment: I've add hibernate.cfg.xml file content. Maybe there it's something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```
DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

And based on Spring.io documentation:

> You often do not need to specify the driver-class-name, since Spring
>   Boot can deduce it for most databases from the URL.

To create a single Jar file with all dependencies which won't rise such this error, as you've added `maven-assembly-plugin` in pom.xml you can use `mvn package` command to create a jar with all dependency and it will be created in `target/settlement-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: Without line spring.datasource.driver-class-name application won't start even by IDE. With this line problem exists only with app started from IDE

Comment: Can you access your Mysql instance with exactly given URL and other parameters in the other DB IDE?

Comment: Sorry, I've messed up in pom.xml. Now, when I've correct pom.xml and application.properties, application is running without line spring.datasource.driver-class-name, but still only from IDE, not from JAR. Please check updated question with correct pom.xml and application.properties files

Comment: I've add hibernate.cfg.xml file content. Maybe there it's something wrong

Comment: This exception which I've posted in question.

Comment: @MTretowski How did you create Jar file? and how you run it? please ensure that all required dependency has embedded in Jar and set the correct classpath when you want to run the Jar file.

Comment: I'm creating JAR through IDE (IntellJ) - Build -> Build artifacts. Here you have artifact configuration: [link](https://ibb.co/0JwfG6P).

Comment: To check Created Jar file, Open it as zip file and check for mysql library in it. I saw you've add setting for creating fat jar(jar with dependency) in pom.xml.xml,  use Maven to create proper Jar file.

Comment: Yes, I have "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar" in main directory

Comment: Idea with create Jar with Maven was great. I've used mvn install, and it works!

Comment: @MTretowski I've updated my answer to cover the build solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!